OnGet and OnPost not executing for displayed page on ASP.Net Core razor page
I have a partial page that shows a login button in a site banner:
<form id="logoutForm" class="form-inline" method="post" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/SessionLoggedOut">
    <button id="logout" type="submit" class="btnAsLink">Logout</button>
</form>

When I click on the button, the SessionLoggedOut page displays, but my onGet and OnPost do not seem to be executed.  I also added logging statements and don't see those in the logs.  My goal is to sign the user out when they get to that page, but I can't seem to execute anything when that page is displayed.  Here are the current onGet and onPost (I get that it's probably unecessary to have the same code in both, but just trying to see which method gets hit and hether seem to be):
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
{
    _logger.LogInformation("SessionLoggedOut.OnGet executed");
    await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    
    return Page();
}

public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    _logger.LogInformation("SessionLoggedOut.OnPost executed");
    await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);


    return Page();
}


I tested with your code and the code snippet is correct, the onPostAsync gets hit as expected. Please check the browser log to get more information, or you can restart a new Razor project with identity to check the difference. You can also provide more details so that I can reproduce a minimal project sample.

Turns out that I'd left out the namespace declaration on that make and after I added it, the page executed as expected.

As it turned out, I had left out the namespace declaration in that particular page, after adding it, the OnGet was executed as expected.
